# can't convert to "string" C#

Tags: c#

I am creating a school project, the teacher said something with privacy, I'm making a encryption tool but always in EncryptFile(files, password) code return me this error

> can't convert System.Collections.Generic.List to "string"

This is the function then list all files from specific directory to List string, ignoring the exceptions

```
public List<string> GetFiles(string path, string pattern)
{
    var files = new List<string>();
    try
    {
        files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(path, pattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly));
        foreach (var directory in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
            files.AddRange(GetFiles(directory, pattern));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // unnautorized files
    }
    return files;

    string password = ChooseUrPass.Text
    EncryptFile(files, password); //here happen the error
}
```

How can I bypass this error? sorry if its a bad question, I'm newbie

If need theres is the function then encrypt the files

```
public void EncryptFile(string file, string password)
{

    byte[] bytesToBeEncrypted = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
    byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);

    // Hash the password with SHA256
    passwordBytes = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(passwordBytes);

    byte[] bytesEncrypted = AES_Encrypt(bytesToBeEncrypted, passwordBytes);

    File.WriteAllBytes(file, bytesEncrypted);
    System.IO.File.Move(file, file+".SafeFile");
}
```

thanks for your time

Comment: I see unreachable code in your `GetFiles`

Comment: You're passing a List<string> to something that expects a string... Also, like @AleksAndreev points out, that method wont even be called there.

Comment: The error is pretty clear. `EncryptFile(string file, string password)` is expecting a single string containing a filename, and you're passing it `files`, which is a `List<string>` containing multiple filenames. What part of that is unclear? A `string` is not the same as a `List<string>`.

Comment: Copy/Paste code from other person's code without understanding what it does is dangerous...

Comment: wow I'm so dumb, Thank you all guys, Gusman thanks for the advice, I will take it seriously

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `EncryptFile` needs its first argument to be a string, and you give it `files`, which is an list of strings.

I'd suggest solving it this way :

```
foreach(string s in files)
{
    EncryptFile(s, password);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `EncryptFile(string file, string password)` is expecting type `string` but you are passing a variable of type `List<string>`

Try this:

```
foreach(string file in files) {
    EncryptFile(file, password);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a `List<string>` and hand made recursion. Try this code:

```
public List<string> GetFiles(string path, string pattern)
{
    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(path, pattern))
    {
        EncryptFile(file, password);
    }
}
```